# How to Multiple Instances of Java Objects of globally for other services in different packages to use?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, global-variables, helidon

Example, there is a Task.java object, and I have multiple instances of this object, and I need to store all those for other services to access globally.
One possible way I acknowledge is to create a new class of those objects, suppose, Tasks.java

```
Tasks.java {
Task TaskA,
Task TaskB,
Task TaskC
}
```

And store this Tasks instance in Global Context.
Is there a way we can store multiple instances of the same object in global contexts without creating a new class?
One more way might be by using dependency injection in Java which I want to avoid.
Or any other different better way to do this?

I have tried:
`Contexts.globalContext().register(task);`

where task is an instance of Task.java class.
I want to store multiple instances of Task in this global Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at classifier support at https://helidon.io/docs/latest/apidocs/io.helidon.common.context/io/helidon/common/context/Context.html#register(java.lang.Object,T)

Example of using the same at
[https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/bef4b1e3f7d11fc27fcbfd79bd326df43ed0bbe[…]xt/src/test/java/io/helidon/common/context/ListContextTest.java](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/bef4b1e3f7d11fc27fcbfd79bd326df43ed0bbe%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dxt/src/test/java/io/helidon/common/context/ListContextTest.java)